# Check words and synonyms

Tags: arrays, perl, string-matching, synonym

I have an array with some words, and another array with words and synonyms. I'd like to create a third array when I find a matchin word between first and second array. I tried with grep but I'm not able to write the code in a proper way in order to get what I want.
The problem is that elements in array 1 can be found in array 2 at the beginning but also at the end or in the middle.

Maybe it's easier with an exemple:

```
@array1 = qw(chose, abstraction);
@array2 = (
"inspirer respirer",
"incapable",
"abstraction",
"abaxial",
"cause,chose,objet",
"ventral",
"chose,objet"
);
```

The result it should be

```
@array3 = ("abstraction", "cause,chose,objet", "chose,objet");
```

Is it right to use "grep"? 
I'm not able to write a right syntax to solve the problem..
Thank you

Comment: `qw(chose, abstraction)` is the same as `('chose,', 'abstraction')`. Are you sure the comma is there?

Comment: yes I'm sure.. The expression is "chose,abstraction". It has been taken from a text file and the line was actually "chose,abstraction"

Comment: @Jurafsky: So, if the string in `@array1` *should* be `chose,`, are you saying that it should match, `cause,chose,objet`, from `@array2` but not, say, `cause,objet,chose` because there is no comma after it?

Comment: sorry! I did a mistake. Elements in array 1 are 1. chose 2. abstraction.  Elements in array 2 are : cause,chose,objet or chose,objet. So if I have in array 1 element like "chose", I would like to match elements in array 2 like "chose,objet" and "cause,chose,objet".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a regular expression from the array1, then filter the array2 using it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array1 = qw(chose, abstraction);
my @array2 = (
              "inspirer respirer",
              "incapable",
              "abstraction",
              "abaxial",
              "cause,chose,objet",
              "ventral",
              "chose,objet"
             );

my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta $_, @array1; # quotemeta needed for special characters.
$regex = qr/$regex/;
my @array3 = grep /$regex/, @array2;
print "$_\n" for @array3;
```

Comment: my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta $_, @array1; # quotemeta needed for special characters.
why are you using "|" ?

Comment: @Jurafsky: Because it separates alternatives in a regular expression.

Comment: @Jurafsky If this answer is the solution to your question, please take a moment to give it a check mark to close out the question. Currently, none of your 10 questions have a selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have an answer but here is a fun way I thought of.

So, I guess it is like an inverted index.

You take each set of synonyms and make them into an array. Then take each element of that array and put it into a hash as the keys with the value being a reference to the array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array1 = qw(chose abstraction);

my @array2 = ("inspirer respirer",
"incapable",
"abstraction",
"abaxial",
"cause,chose,objet",
"ventral",
"chose,objet"
);

my @array;
push @array, map { /,|\s/ ? [split(/,|\s/, $_)]:[$_] } @array2;

my %construct;


while(my $array_ref = shift(@array)){
    for(@{ $array_ref }){
        push @{ $construct{$_} }, $array_ref;
    }
}

my @array3 = map { s/,//; (@{ $construct{$_} }) } @array1;

print join(', ', @{ $_ }), "\n" for (@array3);
```

EDIT:
Missed apart of the answer before, this one should be complete.